# wordpress custom query confusion

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been using a custom query to pull date ordered posts with a specific category ("Wedding Events" or term_taxonomy_id = '4')from a custom post type (dabg_events).

```
$querystr = "SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts. * 
FROM wp_postmeta, wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '4' 
AND wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_dabg-event-start-date' AND STR_TO_DATE(wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= CURDATE( )
OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_dabg-event-end-date' AND STR_TO_DATE( wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= CURDATE( ) )
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'dabg_events' 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y' ) ASC";
$events = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

This works and gets me the posts I need.  Now I need to find the min(_dabg-event-start-date) and max(_dabg-event-start-date).  My question has two parts.  1. Is there an easier way to query the posts types I'm looking for?  or 2. How do I modify this query to get the min(_dabg-event-start-date) and max(_dabg-event-start-date)?

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit join syntax. In fact, unless you really know what you're doing, don't use implicit (comma) join syntax at all. Also, is there no way that dates can be stored under a DATE datatype? And (finally) it seems to me that the LEFT [OUTER[ JOIN should be an [INNER] JOIN because you're not doing anything else with the data returned from the outer table (and you're presently processing it as an INNER JOIN anyway). For further help, consider posting up an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want.  It's untested, as I don't have any data matching yours.  It'll return dates, not strings - if you need the results as strings you'll need to do a conversion.

```
SELECT min(STR_TO_DATE(s.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y' )) as min_start_date,
       max(STR_TO_DATE(s.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y' )) as max_start_date
FROM wp_posts p
     LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta s ON p.ID = s.post_id AND s.meta_key = '_dabg-event-start-date'
     LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta e ON p.ID = e.post_id AND e.meta_key = '_dabg-event-end-date'
     JOIN wp_term_relationships ON p.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '4' 
  AND ( STR_TO_DATE(s.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= CURDATE() OR STR_TO_DATE( e.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y' ) >= CURDATE() )
  AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND p.post_type = 'dabg_events'
```

I couldn't just add the `max` and `min` to your query, as that could have pulled back a maximum end date instead of the start date you need.